# RIA Service with WCF

Tags: silverlight, service, ria

I am using RIA on top of WCF.
In my WCF i have Insert and update methods which talk to db using the Entity Framework

Now in my domain service which is PersonDomainService i am calling this WCF service using Proxy and converting Person Ria Class to Service Reference Entity Framework Person Class and vice versa everything works fine but the problem is when i use IQueryable methods then my Ria service on top of WCF works fine but for simple methods such as InsertPerson and UpdatePerson where i am not returning any entity my service fails as these simple methods are not generated in the client Ria Code.

So what is the best possible way to overcome this Ria Limitation.
Keep in mind my Ria is not directly taling to EF but its directly talking to the WCF

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be adding an extra layer between RIA and you business/data logic. It would be more efficient to work with RIA directly for CRUD operations. For any simple methods that do not return an entity can be attributed [ServiceOperation].

Answer (score 0):

Shawn Widlermuth talks about this in his blog [here](http://wildermuth.com/2009/09/29/Choosing_a_Data_Access_Layer_for_Silverlight_3). It seems that you are trying two different approaches at the same time. I suggest focusing on one. I am using RIA and it works well for me.